# How to diagnose "An internal error has occurred" loading Revit document in Design Automation?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have an addin for Revit 2023 which is successfully running in Design Automation.  For certain input files I will see an error like this:

```
[05/17/2023 21:59:55] Initialize and  get RCE: (VersionBuild) 23.1.20.50 (VersionNumber) 2023 (SubVersionNumber) 2023.1.20
[05/17/2023 22:00:08] Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InternalException: An internal error has occurred.
[05/17/2023 22:00:08]    at Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application.OpenDocumentFile(ModelPath modelPath, OpenOptions openOptions)
[05/17/2023 22:00:08]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationData..ctor(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[05/17/2023 22:00:08]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs..ctor(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[05/17/2023 22:00:08]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationBridge.SetDesignAutomationReady(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[05/17/2023 22:00:08]    at RevitCoreEngineTest.RceConsoleApplication.Program.UserMain(CommandLineArgs cl)
[05/17/2023 22:00:14] RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure
[05/17/2023 22:00:14] Finished running.  Process will return: TestError
[05/17/2023 22:00:14] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[05/17/2023 22:00:16] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/17/2023 22:00:16] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code 4 which indicates an error.
[05/17/2023 22:00:16] End script phase.
[05/17/2023 22:00:16] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[05/17/2023 22:00:17] Job finished with result FailedExecution
```

I am able to load the files in desktop Revit 2023.

What is the best way to diagnose this problem?

Comment: Could you share more info, like the entire log or workitem id? How many files are affected?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here is a sample workitem id: 74d224df5e5a48d48b567df4533c65bc

This happens sporadically depending on the input .rvt file.  Some are fine and others trigger this crash.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try "adskDebug" to get the Revit journals for debugging? Check the blog post at
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/using-argument-adskdebug-troubleshot-failure-job-design-automation

Comment: Ok, I did that and have the debugInfo.zip file.  What should I do with it?  Can I work with Autodesk support directly or do we have to go through stackoverflow?

Comment: The revit journal file help to debug the issue, if you don't have idea about the issue, please share with us at aps.help@autodesk.com.